# Does this part have anything to do with a C.V. drive axle?

Tags: axle, cv-joint

I was changing my cv drive axle and when I went back out to the street I noticed this part lying with all of my stuff. I'm not sure about what it is but I'm kinda worried. It's clean and smooth, and there is no residue on it.

[image: Photo 1] [image: Photo 2] [image: Photo 3]

Answer (score 1):

It was a part of the slide hammer I used to get the drive axle out that came dislodged while using it.

Comment: Remember: if you don't have parts left over, you're doing it wrong. :)